# Can Armory be used for mining?

Tags: wallet, armory, mining-software

Can Armory be used for mining?
I hear it is a wallet, but as it downloads the whole blockchain anyway should not you be able to mine with it, too?

Answer (score 2):

Armory uses Bitcoin Core to download blocks and other basic functionality. Bitcoin Core is what is normally used for mining so that's what you'd be using. Armory does not add anything useful for mining. When you mine you can send the mining income to an Armory wallet without Armory taking part in the mining process.